# disabling HTTP caching have different behavior between mobile and PC

Tags: android, node.js, google-chrome, http, caching

I have a node.js server that uses express with serveStatic middleware to serve some static files.

I disable all file caching by using `Cache-Control: no-store` in HTTP header.

everything works fine when I test it from Chrome on Windows PC. It serves all files correctly and when I change any of those files and refresh the page, it would get updated immediately.

But when I using Chrome on Android mobile phones, it will not try to re-fetch all files at all page refresh. specially it will never try to re-fetch index.html.

It seems the caching mechanism is different on android and windows. On windows it would re-fetch index.html and other files on all page refreshes.

Do you have any clue about this behavior?
Thanks a lot